# Не подключается MySQL к Qt

Tags: mysql, qt

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtSql>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setPort(3306);
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("root");
    db.setDatabaseName("base");

    if(db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "connected " << db.hostName();
    }else{
        qDebug() << "Connection FAILED.";

    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Имя ошибки "SSL connection error: unknown error number QMYSQL: Unable to connect"

Comment: А база MYSQL на localhost точно развернута? Там есть внутри база данных `base`? Вход под записью root разрешен?

Comment: возможно с портом ошибка. В этом случае вы не туда стучитесь при подключении. Добавьте полную конфигурацию MYSQL в вашей системе и вывод команды `netstat -tunlp` или `ss -tunl`

Comment: база данных есть base есть. Под данными root я обычно захожу в mysql workbench. А открыт ли доступ внешне не знаю как узнать